# Stagger Flutter animated list itembuilder animation

Tags: flutter

I have a sliver animated sliver list where each item is generated with the following function:

```dart
Widget _buildIntroItem(BuildContext context, AnimatedChatState state, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: SizeTransition(
        axis: Axis.vertical,
        sizeFactor: animation,
        child: _buildIntroCard(context, state.messageList[index])
      ),
    );
  }
```

When the items animate in the list, they increase in size and opacity at the same time. How can I stagger the transition so that they increase in size, then increase in opacity?

Comment: check `Interval` class documentation

Comment: add animation controller and animation.